# Virtualbox Network adapter issue

Tags: windows, virtualbox, network-adapter

Is there a way to install a host-only network. I have tried many methods none of them worked for me! Only NAT and NAT network is available for me. please help... any solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Try here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox and skip down to the section on Host Only Networking.

Quote "Customized network interfaces will be used on the host system for the host-only network, such as: vboxnet0. The IP address on the host as well as the DHCP server for this network will be configured directly in VirtualBox:"